# Django form submission - unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, django, with-statement

I have a form on one of my Django webpages, which currently displays information about Budgets for a particular Project. Budget & Project are both models within the database.

Each Project can have multiple Budgets, but only one of those Budgets will be the 'current Budget'.

The way the information is displayed, is that there are a number of 'tile' icons called 'Presentations', (one for each Budget). When one of the 'Presentation' tiles is selected, a form is displayed below the tiles, for the user to fill in information about that presentation (notes, who is attending, date, etc). The last 'tile' icon in the list will always be a blank tile, titled "Add presentation", which the user can click to add a new presentation for the project- and it will display a blank copy of the form beneath the existing tiles.

The form includes two fields for uploading images (the images will be associated with that particular Project through the Budget object that they are uploaded to.

Once the form has been filled out, and the image files added to the form, the user should click the 'Submit' button at the bottom of the form to upload this all to the database. Then, when returning to this page, they should be able to click on the 'tile' icon for that particular presentation, and the form should be displayed, automatically populated with the information they had entered previously, and with any image files that they had uploaded attached to it.

This currently works as expected, however, for some reason, when clicking the 'Upload' button at the bottom of the form, to upload the images and other information entered into the form to the Budget for the Project, it seems to add two more blank 'Presentation' tiles to the webpage... and I really don't understand why this is happening...

The HTML for this form is:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-vat-status="{{project.vat_status}}" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:concept_save_ajax_2' project.id %}" class="autosave_form formset full-width" action="{% url 'projects:upload_budget_pdfs' project.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div id="presentations" class="app-wrap center-apps middle">
        {% with get|apps:'Budgets' as costing_app %}
            {% for presentation in presentations %}
                <div id="presentation-{{presentation.id}}" class="app sm {% if presentation.current_marker %}{{costing_app.color}}{% else %}{{app.color}}{% endif %}">
                    <a href="" class="filler"></a>
                    <a class="show-presentation bottom-right" name="presentation-{{presentation.id}}"><img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/edit-white.png' %}"></a>

                    <ul class="flush">
                        <li class=""><h2 class="p-t-lg">Presentation {{forloop.counter}}</h2></li>
                        <li>{{presentation.presentation_date|date:"d M y"|xor}}</li>
                        <li>{{presentation.details|xor|truncatechars:50}}</li>
                        {% if presentation.current_marker %}<li>({% if project.deposit_received%}Deposit{% else %}Current{% endif %} budget)</li>{% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>

            {% if forloop.last %}
            {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
                {# Add a new presentation #}
            <div id="presentation-new" class="app sm {{costing_app.color}} outline">
                <a id="new_presentation" data-view-url="{% url 'projects:save_new_presentation' project.id %}" class="filler show-presentation" name="presentation-new"></a>
                <a name="presentation-new"></a>
                <span class="big-head">+</span>
                <h2 class="no-m">Add presentation</h2></li>
            </div>
        {% endwith %}
    </div>

    <div class="middle">
        {{presentation_formset.management_form}}
        {{drawing_formset.management_form}}

        <div class="col-9 centered-block p-t-lg">
            <table class="left fixed text-sm slim">
        {# New presentation without budget #}
                <tbody>

                </tbody>




        {# Edit presentation details #}
                {% for presentation_form in presentation_formset %}
                    <tbody id="pres{{forloop.counter}}" class="presentation-form" name="presentation-{{presentation_form.instance.id|xor:'new'}}" style="display: none;">


                        {% if not forloop.last and presentation_form.instance.budget_items.count %}
                            <tr class="split-rows">
                                <td colspan="3">Exc VAT {% if not presentation_form.instance.current_marker %}{{presentation_form.instance.grand_total_exc_vat|money:'£'}}{% else %}{{project.budget_overview.updated_exc_vat|money:'£'}}{% endif %}</td>
                                <td colspan="3">Inc VAT {% if not presentation_form.instance.current_marker %}{{presentation_form.instance.grand_total_inc_vat|money:'£'}}{% else %}{{project.budget_overview.updated_inc_vat|money:'£'}}{% endif %}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                            <tr>
                                {% for hidden in presentation_form.hidden_fields %}
                                    <td class="hidden">{{ hidden }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tr>
                            {% for field in presentation_form.visible_fields %}
                                <tr class="split-rows">
                                    {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
                                        <td colspan="6"><label>{{field.label}}</label></td>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </tr>

                                <tr class="split-rows">

                                    <td colspan="6">
                                        {% if not field.name == 'pdf_package_dep' %}
                                            {% if field.name == 'presentation_date' %}
                                                {% with presentation_form.instance.meeting as meeting %}
                                                    {% include "projects/includes/meeting_bit.html" with employee=request.user.employee meeting=meeting UID=presentation_form.instance.id %}
                                                {% endwith %}
                                                {# <a class="ical_trigger button" data-view-url="{% url 'events:add_to_cal' %}" {% if not field.value %}style="display:none"{% endif %}>Add to calendar</a> #}
                                            {% else %}
                                                {{field}}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}

                            {% if presentation_form.instance.id %}

                                {# PDF uploads #}
                                {% with drawing_form=drawing_formset|getval:forloop.counter0  %}
                                    {# budget_pdf_form=budget_pdf_formset|getval:forloop.counter0 #}
                                    <tr>
                                        {% if not forloop.last %}
                                            <td colspan="3"><label>Budget PDF package</label></td>
                                        {% endif %}

                                        <td colspan="3"><label>Drawings</label></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        {% if not forloop.last %}
                                            <td colspan="3" class="center">
                                                {% if presentation_form.instance.pdf_package_dep %}
                                                    <a class="button file-download pdf" href="{% url 'costing:pdf_open' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=package_dep" target="_blank"></a><a class="pdf-clear" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:pdf_clear' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=package_dep"><img class="icon m-l-sm m-b-md" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    {{presentation_form.pdf_package_dep}}
                                                {% endif %}
                                            </td>       
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% for d_field in drawing_form.visible_fields %}
                                            {% if drawing_form.instance.pdf %}
                                                <td colspan="3" class="center">
                                                    <a class="button file-download pdf" href="{% url 'costing:pdf_open' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=drawings" target="_blank"></a><a class="pdf-clear" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:pdf_clear' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=drawings"><img class="icon m-l-sm m-b-md" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>
                                                    <!--ERF(27/01/2017 @ 1135) Need a hidden field to actually hold the file that's uploaded to the form -->
                                                    <input type="hidden" name = "conceptDrawing" value="{{d_field.title}}">
                                                    <!--ERF(27/01/2017) Need to include the formset in the template -->
                                                    {#{ drawing_formset.as_table }#}
                                                    {{drawing_form.as_table}} 
                                                    {{ drawing_formset.management_form }}
                                                </td>       
                                            {% else %}
                                                <td colspan="3">{{d_field}}</td>
                                                {% for d_hidden in drawing_form.hidden_fields %}
                                                    <td class="hidden">{{d_hidden}}</td>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="1" class="p-t-md"></td>
                                            <td colspan="4" class="p-t-md"><input type="submit" value="upload"></td>
                                            <td colspan="1" class="p-t-md"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endwith %}
                            {% endif %}


                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">

                                <a class="button email_trigger m-t-md" style="width:auto;" data-view-url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=6&budget={{presentation_form.instance.id}}">Email client meeting report</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td class="p-t-md">
                                <a {% if forloop.last %}id="refresh_presentations"{% endif %}class="update_presentation button fill">Done</a>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                {% if presentation_form.instance.id and not presentation_form.instance.budget_items.count %}
                                    <a class="button fill" href="{% url 'costing:delete_presentation' presentation_form.instance.id %}">Delete</a>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the `upload_budget_pdfs()` view that is called when the form is submitted is:

```
def upload_budget_pdfs(request, project_id):
    project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
    print("Value of project in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", project)

    if request.method == 'POST':

    presentations = project.budget_versions.select_related('meeting').prefetch_related('budget_items', 'cci_items', 'presenters').filter(version_number__isnull=False).annotate(vn=F('version_number') * -1).order_by('presentation_date', 'created', '-vn')
    print("Value of presentations in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", presentations)
    drawing_formset = DrawingUploadFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix="drawings", queryset=Drawing.objects.filter(budget__in=presentations).order_by('budget__presentation_date', 'budget__created'))

    print("Value of drawing_formset in 'upload_budget_pdfs()': ", drawing_formset)

    if drawing_formset:
        print "Before", [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]

        try:
            for drawing_form in drawing_formset: 
                print 'for loop entered in upload_budget_pdfs() - line 1034'
                print "Value of drawing_form: ", drawing_form
                if drawing_form.instance.budget:
                    print 'if statement entered - line 1036 '
                    print 'Instance', drawing_form.instance.budget
                    drawing = drawing_form.save(commit=False)
                    drawing.budget = drawing_form.instance.budget
                    drawing.save()
                print drawing, [b.id for b in project.budget_versions.all()]
        except Exception as e:
            print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
    else: 
        print("Drawing formset not valid. ", drawing_formset.errors)



    budget_formset = BudgetPresentationFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=project, prefix="presentations")

    try:
        if budget_formset.is_valid() and budget_formset.has_changed():
            print("if budget_formset.is_valid() statement entered (line 1063) ")
            #updated_budget_presentations = budget_formset.save()
            budget_formset.save()
            print("Value of update_budget_presentations: ", updated_budget_presentations)
        elif budget_formset.has_changed(): print 'Budget formset not valid.',budget_formset.errors
    except Exception as e:
        print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('projects:concept', args=[project_id]))
```

The blank 'Presentation' tiles are only added to the page when submitting a form if there are 'PDF Packages' attached to it (i.e. images added to the form using the first 'upload image' button)... They are not added to the page if the form is submitted when there are no 'PDF Packages' attached to it- no matter whether or not there are 'drawing' PDFs attached to it (i.e. the images added to the form using the second 'upload image' button).

The section of the HTML being used to upload the images for the 'PDF Packages' & 'Drawings' to the form is:

```
{% with drawing_form=drawing_formset|getval:forloop.counter0  %}
    {# budget_pdf_form=budget_pdf_formset|getval:forloop.counter0 #}
    <tr>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <td colspan="3"><label>Budget PDF package</label></td>
        {% endif %}

        <td colspan="3"><label>Drawings</label></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <td colspan="3" class="center">
                {% if presentation_form.instance.pdf_package_dep %}
                    <a class="button file-download pdf" href="{% url 'costing:pdf_open' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=package_dep" target="_blank"></a><a class="pdf-clear" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:pdf_clear' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=package_dep"><img class="icon m-l-sm m-b-md" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>
                {% else %}
                    {{presentation_form.pdf_package_dep}}
                {% endif %}
            </td>       
        {% endif %}
        {% for d_field in drawing_form.visible_fields %}
            {% if drawing_form.instance.pdf %}
                <td colspan="3" class="center">
                    <a class="button file-download pdf" href="{% url 'costing:pdf_open' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=drawings" target="_blank"></a><a class="pdf-clear" data-view-url="{% url 'costing:pdf_clear' presentation_form.instance.id %}?pdf=drawings"><img class="icon m-l-sm m-b-md" src="{% static "img/bin.png" %}"></a>

                    <input type="hidden" name = "conceptDrawing" value="{{d_field.title}}">

                    {#{ drawing_formset.as_table }#}
                    {{drawing_form.as_table}} 
                    {{ drawing_formset.management_form }}
                </td>       
            {% else %}
                <td colspan="3">{{d_field}}</td>
                {% for d_hidden in drawing_form.hidden_fields %}
                    <td class="hidden">{{d_hidden}}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1" class="p-t-md"></td>
            <td colspan="4" class="p-t-md"><input type="submit" value="upload"></td>
            <td colspan="1" class="p-t-md"></td>
        </tr>
    </tr>
{% endwith %}
```

I am wondering if I need to be using the line:

```
{# budget_pdf_form=budget_pdf_formset|getval:forloop.counter0 #}
```

as part of the `{% with ... %}` statement at the top of this section of HTML? But I don't know how I would use the `with` with two different arguments at the same time...? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you could do some testing. try modifying your formset .. say with 1 extra form and zero extra forms and see what happens.